# concatenate variable onto another variable

Tags: c

```
const char *SITE_NAME = "test";
char SITE_ROOT[19];
sprintf (SITE_ROOT, "/var/www/html/%s", SITE_NAME);
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting an error of:

> error: expected ‘)’ before string constant

Basically I just want to concatenate the variable SITE_NAME onto SITE_ROOT. The error is on the sprintf line. Any ideas?

UPDATE: So the code works if it is inside main(). I had it outside of main() so that I could use those variables inside of functions.

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: @JackManey - I have updated my post...the error is on the sprintf line.

Comment: An unexpected macro may be messing things up. Check the preprocessor output. (`cc -E file.c` for unix-like compilers; tell what compiler you're using if you need more help)

Comment: You wrote: "I had it outside of main()"... that's not how C works.

Comment: Note that you can still keep the **variables** outside of any function and use them globally, it's the `sprintf` call that's the problem. I'm curious, though, as to why you're trying to do it this way instead of `const char SITE_ROOT[] = "/var/www/html/test";`. What exactly are you trying to accomplish by splitting it up and immediately doing the concatenation?

Comment: I don't want to type the SITE_NAME a bunch of times when it already is in a variable. I figured I could just set the SITE_NAME and I'm done rather than worrying about a bunch of other variables that would be affected.

Comment: @Jerry - Is there a difference between `const char SITE_ROOT[] = "/var/www/html/test";` and `const char SITE_ROOT = "/var/www/html/test";`?

Comment: Yes, only the first will compile, did you mean to make the second a pointer? In any case, even if you're concerned about DRY/SSOT, you could use macros (or, more hackishly, a single string and a pointer into that string if you don't like macros).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out, the direct problem is that you're trying to call `sprintf` from outside a function.

You mentioned that you are setting the strings this way because you're using `SITE_NAME` by itself in addition to concatenating it with the path and you want to only have to change it in one place. This is a good goal, known in some circles as ["don't repeat yourself" (often abbreviated DRY)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). However, even if the code worked (say, because you moved the `sprintf` call into main), you haven't really achieved your goal due to the following line:

```
char SITE_ROOT[19];
```

You are declaring a fixed length array exactly big enough to hold `"/var/www/html/test"`, which is just asking for a buffer overflow. When you change `SITE_NAME` from `"test"` to, for example, `"someRealSiteName"`, you'll very probably overwrite something else when you concatenate, causing unpredictable results. So you have to manually recalculate the length of the final string and update the array size (which would be easy to get wrong, say by forgetting to add 1 for the null terminator) every time you change `SITE_NAME`.

You could, of course, limit the length of `SITE_NAME` and size `SITE_ROOT` to hold the longest possible path, but it'd be an artificial limit and you might end up wasting space. Furthermore, you'd still have to verify the length isn't exceeded at run-time (or use a function that will ignore extra characters).

Instead, you could dynamically set the size of `SITE_ROOT` like so:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const char SITE_PATH[] = "/var/www/html/";
const char SITE_NAME[] = "someRealSiteName";
char *SITE_ROOT = NULL; // just making this explicit, would be set to 0 anyway

int main(void)
{
    size_t siteRootLength = strlen(SITE_PATH) + strlen(SITE_NAME);

    SITE_ROOT = malloc(siteRootLength + 1); //don't forget to account for the terminating '\0'

    strcpy(SITE_ROOT, SITE_PATH);
    strcat(SITE_ROOT, SITE_NAME);

    printf("%s\n", SITE_NAME):
    printf("%s\n", SITE_PATH):
    printf("%s\n", SITE_ROOT):

    return 0;
}
```

This solution is okay, but has some drawbacks:

- `SITE_ROOT` can't be a `const` pointer , so both the string and the pointer itself could be accidentally changed
- Site path and name will each be in memory twice (though it sounds like you're okay with that)
- Concatenation is being done at run-time when it could be done at compile-time
- Code is longer and more complex than necessary for such a simple task
- Risk that `SITE_ROOT` is used before it has the correct value (or is even a valid pointer/string!) in some other initialization code or another thread.

I feel something like the following is better:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SITE_PATH_MACRO "/var/www/html/"
#define SITE_NAME_MACRO "someRealSiteName"

// the preprocessor will merge the two string literals into one
#define SITE_ROOT_MACRO SITE_PATH_MACRO SITE_NAME_MACRO

// you could do without some or all of these if you don't need them
// (or are willing to use the macros directly)
const char SITE_PATH[] = SITE_PATH_MACRO;
const char SITE_NAME[] = SITE_NAME_MACRO;
const char SITE_ROOT[] = SITE_ROOT_MACRO;

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", SITE_NAME);
    printf("%s\n", SITE_PATH);
    printf("%s\n", SITE_ROOT);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user983223 I'm glad you found it helpful. I should point out that the merging of string literals doesn't only work in conjunction with macros, it just happens to be most useful there. So you could do `const char SITE_ROOT[] = SITE_PATH_MACRO SITE_NAME_MACRO` to get rid of one macro or `const char SITE_ROOT[] = "/var/www/html/" SITE_NAME_MACRO` to get rid of two (if you didn't need the `SITE_PATH` variable)

Answer (score 4):

The error looks like it might not be shown in the code but the `sprintf` should be:

```
sprintf (SITE_ROOT, "/var/www/html/%s", SITE_NAME);
```

**EDIT:**

Here is my complete test code if that helps at all:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char *SITE_NAME = "test";
    char SITE_ROOT[19];
    sprintf (SITE_ROOT, "/var/www/html/%s", SITE_NAME);

    printf( "%s\n", SITE_ROOT ) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: I have taken off the ampersand in front of SITE_NAME and it is still giving an error. I added the ampersand because I thought SITE_NAME is defined as a pointer and to call that pointer I need to put an ampersand, no?

Comment: @user983223 It is odd, I cannot reproduce that error at all. The `%s` format specifier expect a c style string which is a `char *` which is what `SITE_NAME` is. I will update my post with my complete test code in case that helps.

Comment: @Shafik_Yaghmour - That standalone code works. I'll divide and conquer and try and figure out what function is not liking it.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour - The code works because the variables are defined inside of main(). I hade them outside of main() so that the variables would be available to other functions.

Comment: @user983223 Ah, ok, that makes more sense. You can have global variables but you can not have statements like sprintf outside of `main` of a function.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a pretty straightforward case, you can simply initialize the string and then concatenate onto it.  You might want to add checks to ensure you don't go beyond you string's boundaries though.

```
strcpy(SITE_ROOT, "/var/www/html/"); 
strcat(SITE_ROOT, SITE_NAME);
```

Comment: If you're going to keep `SITE_ROOT` as a fixed length buffer (which it seems you're implying), you can directly initialize it with `char SITE_ROOT[19] = "/var/www/html/"` and skip the `strcpy` call.